# Bash write ls error to file

Tags: linux, bash, file, output, ls

I have a folder with lots of files named with a continuing number and some text, but some numbers are missing. I want to write all missing numbers into a file.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=23457; c<=24913; c++ ))
do
  files=$(printf %q kassensystem/documents/"${c}")
  ret=$(ls $files*)
  echo "$ret" >> ./out.log
done
```

The output looks like that:

all existing files are written into file, all errors into console. I want exactly the other way. All errors (`ls: ..file not found`) written into the file!

I tried to use the complete command `ls $files* | grep -v 'kasse*'`, but then I only get a file with empty lines.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Error messages go to `stderr`, you're only capturing `stdout`.

Comment: `ls` should never be used for this kind of case. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- the shell itself can expand globs to populate lists of names, so calling an external tool built principally to generate output for humans is needless.

Comment: BTW, putting `>>out.txt` in a loop is very inefficient -- it *reopens the file* every time that line is executed.

Comment: ...as another aside, using `printf %q` is good practice when you're generating text to be substituted into a string which will be parsed as a shell command (be that via `eval "ls $files*"`, or `ssh "$host" "ls $files*"`, or `sh -c "ls $files*"`, or such), but it's not needed (and, in fact, counterproductive) when there's no such shell-parsing happening on the variable's contents. An unquoted expansion such as `ls $files` only does string-splitting and glob-expansion, it doesn't process backspaces or quotes that `printf %q` might create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec 4>out.log  # open output file just once, not once per write

for (( c=23457; c<=24913; c++ )); do
  files=( kassensystem/documents/"$c"* ) # glob into an array
  [[ -e $files ]] || echo "$c" >&4       # log if first file in array doesn't exist
done
```

Comment: I think this solution is the better one. plus I only write the numbers not the entire stderr into file